# Can't get the xcode storyboard modal buttons to change screen

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I've been following an ios tutorial where I'm required to create multiple view controllers with different screens and connect buttons with modals. I've set up the buttons propertly and even set up the modal settings, but when I run the iphone simulator, nothing happens when i click the button. Is this a bug or am i doing something wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you post the link of your tutorial?

Comment: I'm going through Meng's design + code tutorial. The book + videos doesn't have a public link

Comment: I've created multiple buttons that link to different screens, but none of them work when I run the simulator. I clicked everywhere on the sceren and theres no transition at all

Comment: Did you link your button with your code? On XCode, active splitView (two circles button on the top right), rightClick on your button, click on "Touch Up Inside", drag to your class Controller, it will create a function, then log something( println("button Clicked") ). If you can make a Repo on Github with your project, I will check it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. What do you mean by link your button with the code? I'm just trying to create a modal connection between different screens.

Answer (score 1):

**its probably a problem with your storyboard connections**

- Open your storyboard
- Open the right utilities panel in Xcode
- Select the connections inspector tab
- Select the different views/buttons involved in the failed interaction, and check the connections panel.

*My guess is it's the button's connections - either it's missing or its trying to link to a connection that isn't existing*